# Is it appropriate to use BackgroundWorker to do work that raises an event that I listen for

Tags: c#, loops, backgroundworker, event-handling

I'm new to Threading but I've read threads here on BackgroundWorker (BW) and mostly understand the material.  I suspect BW is not the correct solution but let me ask.
I have an object (GPS Emulator) that does its work in a loop mostly waiting (Thread.Sleep()) but occasionally raising an event that the UI listens for.  I want the UI to be responsive of course so it would be nice to put the work of the object in the background (as in gps.Start()).  On the UI I want to have the ability to Pause, Resume, and Stop the GPS.  I figured I could do this by setting appropriate flags in the GPS object that would break the loop running in the background.  What I don't understand is what happens to the events that are raised by the GPS.  The Thread that the event is raised on is not the Thread that is listening and so it seems, the UI can't respond correctly (as in painting the new GPS point on the UI).
Am I missing something wrt BW or is there a better (but still simple) way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use the [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event of the BackgroundWorker to monitor the the event on your own thread.

---

**Update**

---

If you want to pass custom information like GeoCordinates to the Main UI thread you can do so by Using the Overloaded Method of [ReportProgress(Int32 progresschanged, object userstate)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) method.

### Example:

*This is just an example modify it according to your requirement*

Create a class to hold cordinates postion:

```
public class Position
{
    public int Lat{get;set;}
    public int Long {get;set;}
}
```

In your [`DoWork`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) method do somthing like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //Perform what ever is your task and when you get somthing like a GeoPosition cordinate 
    Position pos = new Position(); 
    pos.Lat = 100; 
    pos.Long = 200; // just some position data
    //pass it on to progress changed event
    //any integer between 0 to 100 that tells how much you have done or just pass 0
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress( 0, pos);       
}
```

in your progress changed event handler :

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
        //retrieve position from userstate
        Position pos = e.UserState as Position;
        some_counter_or_progressbar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        textboxLatitude.Text = pos.Lat.ToString();
        textboxLongitude.Text = pos.Long.ToString();
}
```

I'm sure you got the Idea...

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Maybe I didn't explain the problem well.

Comment: gps.Start() loops until the next point in a previously stored GPS track is ready to fire at which time the OnNewPoint event is raised.  The UI is looking for this event so that it can update a lot of controls on its surface.  It is however prevented by a cross thread error which prevents modifying any of the controls without resorting to the use of Invoke which is a pain.  I don't see how I can use ProgressChanged to pass on the OnNewPoint event

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood this right, the events fired by the GPS emulator result in an UI update and you want to be able to control the running of the GPS emulator from your UI. If this is indeed correct, I'd use the event WaitHandle constructs, either Auto or Manual based on the situation

Comment: I ave no trouble controlling the gps from the UI.  The problem I wanted to solve was the UI's responsiveness, so I tried putting the gps working loop in the background.  Trouble is, the UI is prevented from changing any of it's controls by a cross thread error unless I resort to a bunch of extra (and complicated) work.  Search for How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls